# Emacs: How do I use flymake-cursor in Evil's normal mode?

Tags: emacs, evil

I'm a Vim fan trying out Emacs with the Evil mode. After configuring FlyMake to use the flake8 command, I have nearly the same editor configuration in Emacs that I'm used to in Vim. The only problem out-of-the-box is I can't see descriptions of the errors that FlyMake is highlighting without hovering over the problematic code with my mouse.

I learned about the flymake-cursor extension and installed it, and now I can also see the errors when I enter insert mode, which is an improvement. However since most cursor movement is done in normal mode, having to enter insert mode to see an error message is an annoyance (albeit relatively minor). The ideal would be to show the errors when my cursor is over the line in normal mode.

Does anyone know how I can configure Emacs to behave this way?

Answer (score 0):

Someone on the #evil-mode channel suggested I use [FlyCheck](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck) instead of FlyMake. This seems to simply work out-of-the-box with the Evil mode.